# http proxy cache server not limiting browser functionality

Tags: python, http, caching, https, proxy

I am trying to use this code to create an HTTP proxy cache server. When I run the code it starts running and connects to the port and everything but when I try to connect from the browser, for example, it opens a port on 55555 if I type in `localhost:52523/www.google.com` it works fine but when I try other sites specifically HTTP, for example, `localhost:52523/www.microcenter.com` or just `localhost:52523/google.com` it will display localhost didn’t send any data.

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and shows an exception in the console though it creates the cache file on my computer.

I would like to find out how to edit the code so that I can access any website just as I would normally do on the browser without using the proxy server. It should be able to work with `www.microcenter.com`

```
import socket
import sys
import urllib
from urlparse import urlparse
Serv_Sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # socket.socket 
function creates a socket.
port = Serv_Sock.getsockname()[1]
# Server socket created, bound and starting to listen
Serv_Sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # socket.socket 
function creates a socket.
Serv_Sock.bind(('',port))
Serv_Sock.listen(5)
port = Serv_Sock.getsockname()[1]
# Prepare a server socket
print ("starting server on port %s...,"%(port)) 



def caching_object(splitMessage, Cli_Sock):
    #this method is responsible for caching
    Req_Type = splitMessage[0]
    Req_path = splitMessage[1]
    Req_path = Req_path[1:]
    print "Request is ", Req_Type, " to URL : ", Req_path

    #Searching available cache if file exists
    url = urlparse(Req_path)
    file_to_use = "/" + Req_path
    print file_to_use
    try:
        file = open(file_to_use[5:], "r")
        data = file.readlines()
        print "File Present in Cache\n"

        #Proxy Server Will Send A Response Message
        #Cli_Sock.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n")
        #Cli_Sock.send("Content-Type:text/html")
        #Cli_Sock.send("\r\n")

        #Proxy Server Will Send Data
        for i in range(0, len(data)):
            print (data[i])
            Cli_Sock.send(data[i])
        print "Reading file from cache\n"

    except IOError:
        print "File Doesn't Exists In Cache\n fetching file from server \n 
creating cache"
        serv_proxy = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        host_name = Req_path
        print "HOST NAME:", host_name
        try:
            serv_proxy.connect((url.host_name, 80))
             print 'Socket connected to port 80 of the host'
            fileobj = serv_proxy.makefile('r', 0)
            fileobj.write("GET " + "http://" + Req_path + " HTTP/1.0\n\n")

            # Read the response into buffer
            buffer = fileobj.readlines()

            # Create a new file in the cache for the requested file.
            # Also send the response in the buffer to client socket
            # and the corresponding file in the cache
            tmpFile = open(file_to_use, "wb")
            for data in buffer:
                        tmpFile.write(data)
                        tcpCliSock.send(data)
        except:
            print 'Illegal Request'

    Cli_Sock.close()
while True:
    # Start receiving data from the client
    print 'Initiating server... \n Accepting connection\n'
    Cli_Sock, addr = Serv_Sock.accept() # Accept a connection from client
    #print addr

    print ' connection received from: ', addr
    message = Cli_Sock.recv(1024) #Recieves data from Socket

    splitMessage = message.split()
    if len(splitMessage) <= 1:
        continue

    caching_object(splitMessage, Cli_Sock)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http proxy server only working for https sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062396/http-proxy-server-only-working-for-https-sites)

Answer (score 0):

There is a few errors in the code :-

The first is that a `GET` request does not expect the protocol to be passed in as part of the call, nor does it expect the host, instead the `GET` should be restricted to only the path + query string.

An additional `HOST` header should be added which specifies which host you are using (i.e [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) ) some web servers may be setup to ignore this and instead send you a default page, but results are intermittent.

You should have a peek at the [HTTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) which gives some other headers that can be passed via `HTTP`.

You could also install something like `Fiddler` or `Wireshark` and monitor some sample `HTTP` calls and see how the payload is supposed to look.